# Visual C# - Tabbed Program

Tags: c#

What can i use to make multiple tabs that run multiple forms in my visual C# program. I need it to work like an internet browser so you can switch back and forth..

Comment: WinForms, WPF or maybe even ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `TabControl` class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Use a [TabControl (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx) or a [TabControl (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4akwf92a.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use a TabControl Class, you can add it through the Toolbox in the designer view of Visual Studio or add it programatically.

Set the Dock property to Fill.  This will give the internet browser look that you seek.